# How to extend d3 with related library in typescript/webpack environment?

Tags: typescript, d3.js, webpack

I'm trying to use the d3.tip extension with d3v4 inside a typescript/webpack build.

I've tried to implement this with two different d3.tip forks which have modified the library to be up to date with d3v4. These can be found [here](https://github.com/VACLab/d3-tip) and [here](https://github.com/cgav/d3-tip).

I've then installed @types/d3-tip which can be found [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/d3-tip)

After installing the types, and then requiring the code inside my main index file like;

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';

require('./d3-tip.js');

var tip = d3.tip()
```

I keep getting a compile error -

`error TS2339: Property 'tip' does not exist on type 'typeof "/node_modules/@types/d3/index"'.`

One thing I have tried is to export the d3 tip typings from inside the main d3 typings file, so that the [original d3 typings file](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/d3/index.d.ts) includes;

`export * from 'd3-tip';`

This however has not worked, so I'm not sure how else I could fix it?

I've looked around for similar questions but none offer a definitive answer, and any of the solutions posted did not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [source for the plugin](https://github.com/Caged/d3-tip/blob/master/index.js#L9), it correctly registers itself as an AMD module when required. To correctly import and use, you simply need to name it,

```
import d3tip from 'd3-tip';

d3tip().attr...
```